# How to complete fully-parenthesized infix form?

Tags: java, algorithm

Currently facing the problem?
example:
simple input is not fully-parenthesized infix form：
319*((5.5+12.9)-(4.5/3.0))

Sample Output:( 319 * ( ( 5.5 + 12.9 ) - ( 4.5 / 3.0 ) ) )

#### How to make a fully-parenthesized infix?
Can provide some ideas or algorithms?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: [Do I look like a Guru?](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Answer (score 2):

Parse the result to an [expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) and render the tree back using a [tree traversal of your choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

Comment: This is the answer we're all going to post in some way or another. Basically you need to break up the expression where each `operation` is the root and both operands are the children.